# Internet Explorer's poor performance with Robot Framework

Tags: internet-explorer-8, robotframework

Currently the test scripts I created in Robot Framework runs poorly on IE8. Run times take too long that the Web Application's session times out which fails some of the test cases in the test suite. Upon checking of the logs, I noticed that much of the time spent is when interacting with the contents of the tables particularly the Get Table Cell keyword. The more data I have in that table, the longer the time it takes to run a test case. Any suggestions on how approaches I can use to speed things up with Internet Explorer and Robot Framework?

Note: Approximately 3 minutes is the run time for the test suite when ran against Google Chrome and Firefox but when IE is used it takes more than 30 minutes and it usually fails due to the session time out occurring usually at the last 3 test cases.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of selenium are you using?

Comment: I am currently running selenium 2.18

Answer (score 0):

Are you using xpath locators to find elements on a page? If so, is there any possibility to switch to using ids? xpath is considerably slower than any other alternative by as much as two or three orders of magnitude or more.

Comment: Yes I am using xpaths for my locators since most of the elements that I am seeing in the application have auto generated Ids. So in this case, the xpath locators are causing my test scripts to run poorly in IE?

Comment: @dodong: yes, it is almost certain that your use of xpath on IE is the main cause of your performance issues.

Comment: @BryanOakley What if you're using a keyword like `Input Text` and it's inputting character by character every second or so? The locator is an ID.

Answer (score -1):

Input text is very slow in IE so I created a Keyword that uses inline Jquery script to solve the problem:

```
JQ_Input_Text   [Arguments] ${ELEMENTID}    ${TEXT}
\   ${JQ}=  Catenate    SEPARATOR=  $("#    ${ELEMENTID}    ").val("    ${TEXT} ")
\   ${s2l}= Get Library Instance    Selenium2Library
\   Call Method ${s2l._current_browser()}   execute_script  ${JQ}
```